# Angularjs : $locationProvider.hashPrefix("!") ;

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, hashbang

I  want to show url as "www.test.com/!#" for that i am using $locationProvider.hashPrefix("!") ; but it shows url as "www.test.com/#!" . i want "!" before hash not after hash.

Thanks

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix("!");
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: "app.html",
        controller: "AppCtrl"
    }

    )
        .when('/Program', {
        templateUrl: "detail1.html",
        controller: "Redirect"
    })
        .when('/Program/123456/channel/78458585',

    {
        templateUrl: "details.html",
        controller: "Detail"
    });
});



app.controller("AppCtrl", function ($scope) {

});

app.controller("Detail", function ($scope, $location) {

});

app.controller("Redirect", function ($scope, $location) {
    $location.path("/Program/123456/channel/78458585")
});
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want a `!` in the URL before the fragment identifier begins, then you need to put it in the URL to start with and not try to do it with Angular.

`http://www.example.com/#foo` and `http://www.example.com/#!foo` are different parts of the same page.

But `http://www.example.com/#foo` and `http://www.example.com/!#foo` are different pages altogether.

Comment: it there any waty to do it with angularjs..  $locationProvider.hashPrefix("!") by the name should supposed to append it before hash.why it is appearing after hash.